# Android EventBus - hasSubscriberForEvent() always return false

Tags: android, greenrobot-eventbus

As I understand, the method `hasSubscriberForEvent(Class<?> eventClass)` from EventBus should return true if I'm listening for any Event on this `eventClass`. But it always returns false, I'm not sure why.

In my fragment I register and unregister the EventBus, and declare the method to listen the Post:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    super.onDestroy();
}

public void onEvent(MyDummyObject event) {
    Log.i(TAG,"event received!");
}
```

In my service I need to check if this Fragment is visible or not, one way to do it I assumed would be using `EventBus.getDefault().hasSubscriberForEvent(MyFragment.class)`.
I expected that if EventBus would see that `MyFragment` has anything registered would return true, otherwise would return false.

Am I missing something, or `hasSubscriberForEvent()` does not behave this way?

**Note:** If I do `EventBus.getDefault().post(new MyDummyObject());` the event fires, so I assume the EventBus is being registered and unregistered successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that I misunderstood the method `hasSubscriberForEvent`!

I had to change:

```
EventBus.getDefault().hasSubscriberForEvent(MyFragment.class);
```

to:

```
EventBus.getDefault().hasSubscriberForEvent(MyDummyObject.class)
```

The parameter is the object type we are listening and not the class that is registering and unregistering the EventBus.

For more info check the request for this feature in [this link](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/issues/81).